# Interrupts detach

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

I need to stop 1st interrupt from 2nd interrupt till 2nd interrup finish work... How can I do that?

Here is my 2nd interrupt:

```
void CHECK_IR(){
  detachInterrupt(0);
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    switch(results.value){
      case 16753245:
      Serial.println(results.value);
      if(level == 1){
       level = 1; 

      }else {
        level = 1;
      }
      break;
      case 16724175:
      level = 1.6;
      break;
      case 16718055:
      level = 3;
      break;
      case 16743045:
      level = 5;
      break;
      case 16716015:
      level = 9.9;
      break;
    }
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

1st interrupt:

```
void zero_crosss_int() {

   delayMicroseconds(level*1000);  
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(100); 
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);

}
```

Here I `detachInterrupt(0);` detach 1st interrupt, but it is not right because I need it to work again, so i need interrupt 1st to sleep till 2nd intrrupt finish switch statment. Any solution for this?

Comment: Please describe your design and what you want to achieve. You are asking for a solution to a problem that might just be a misunderstanding of how this works.

Comment: In my 1st interrupt I have `delayMicroseconds` it cause if switch never run... It is the problem. I added above 1st interupt..

Comment: You can re-attach the other interrupt at the end of your interrupt handler.

Comment: How? I tried but not working... Also is there any way to avoid delay?